# Non Identity Primary Key Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a basic MVC application using Entity Framework with the Code First approach.
It contains a Product Model:

```
public class Product
{
      [Key]
      [Column("prodCode")]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Product Code is required.")]
      public string ProductCode { get; set; }

      [Column("prodName")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Name is required.")]
      public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The ProductCode is a Non Identity Primary Key.

Where should I put the logic to validate if the key doesn't already exists when the product is inserted or modified. And how do I send a validation message back to the View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can see that you're using MVC (based on the tag being there) I would tell you to do the validation in your business logic (called by your controller to a method which returns a bool), since you'll need a database connection to do the actual checking in this situation.

Sending a validation message back to the View is simple: If the validation fails in the method have it return false to the controller and then have the controller add something to either your `ViewData` collection and add a line to your View to display this value when `ViewData` contains that specific key.

Comment: This type of logic really belongs in a business logic layer, not in the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think of the `ViewData` part.